# DocuSign JWT Impersonation Issues

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm working through the JWT impersonation flows documented [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) and [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-best-practice/). I'm using C#, and though I have worked through a few of the quick start applications, I'm still having some issues.

#### Existing Flow

The flow I have so far, which seems to be functional in DS sandbox/dev/demo, is:

1. Send user to DocuSign (`oauth/auth`). `scope` is `"signature impersonation"`. (I've tried it with a bunch more permissions thrown in as well.)
2. After DS auth and impersonation grant, user shows back up on my web app with an authorization code
3. Take that authorization code and post it to `oauth/token` to get an access token for my target user
4. Take that access token and call `oauth/userinfo` to get the target user's IDs and URL
5. Create a JWT, sign using shared key pair between my web app and DS, and post it to `oauth/token`. Receive a `200` response with a seemingly-good-looking token.

This all seems to work correctly so far: all DS calls come back with `200`s and data which is shaped as I expect.

#### Problems

The issue is that I can't actually successfully use that token from the final step to perform further action as the user who my app is impersonating. (I am being sure to use the `base_url` for the associated user.) When I request a `GET` from the suggested endpoint (`brands`), I receive this back:

```
{
  "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN",
  "message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed. Authentication for System Application failed."
}
```

The response which provided the authorization token includes an `expires_in` value in the thousands of seconds, and I'm performing all of these requests in serial in my web application. So, expiration or revocation *should* not be possible at this point. I also haven't touched the token at all, so I would expect it to be well formed.

Here's the code I'm using to post to that endpoint, if it's useful:

```
private async Task<IgnoreMe> GetBrands(UserInfoAccount account, AccessTokenResponse accessToken)
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("docusign");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri($"{account.BaseUri}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account.Id}/brands"),
    };
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.AccessToken!);
    
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return IgnoreMe.Fail;
    }
    return IgnoreMe.Succeed;
}
```

The args to this method are the values which came back from previous API calls: the `AccessTokenResponse` is from the impersonation call.

I've also tried sending similar requests to several other top-level user/account endpoints, and have received the same or similar errors for all of them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you use this token with any other endpoints?

Comment: No, I’ve tried it on several

Comment: what about the token from step 3? did you try that token? you don't need to use JWT as well as Auth Code Grant. You need either/or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, the problem was that I had used the wrong ID for the `sub` value when constructing the JWT.

Results from the `oauth/userinfo` endpoint I'm using come back structured as a top-level user ID which is associated with a bucket of accounts. I had used an account ID from one of those buckets rather than the top-level user ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is a mix if Auth Code Grant and JWT. You are using both.

The token from step 3 should work (But you can omit "impersonation" as it's not required for Auth Code Grant).

The token expires after 8 hours. That may be the reason for your error. You'll need to obtain a new one.

Comment: As it turns out, I had been using the wrong ID in my construction of the JWT. I was using the ID of one of the user's accounts instead of their top-level account ID. That fixed it.